# Unable to Bind XtraChart auto-generated series

Tags: c#, charts, devexpress

I'm really struggling with the concept of how to dynamically bind my objects into a chart that I desire.

Imagine I have 10 locations, each sampling a particular value. I store these into ChartData objects, each one having lots of readings. I also have an object which stores a reference to each of my different ChartData objects.

I have data in the following (C#) objects:

```
class DataForCombinedChart
{
    List<ChartData> AllChartData { get; set; }
}

class ChartData {
    String SeriesName { get; set; }
    List<ChartReading> Readings { get; set; }
}

class ChartReading { 
    DateTime SampleTime { get; set; }
    int SampleReading { get; set; }
}
```

For charts of just one of my sample areas, I have simply been binding to a ChartData object. Simple.

However, I now want to make a chart with all (approx 10) of my individual charts onto it.

I have been trying to use Auto-Generated-Series to do this, but whatever I try it appears my objects are not in a format which seems to work. All of the documentation for XtraChart appears to be based on connecting to a database rather than POCO, so I am struggling a bit.

Can somebody advise on the correct class hierarchy I need in order to use Auto-Generated-Series in this manner?

Answer (score 0):

```
class DataForCombinedChart
{
    List<ChartData> AllChartData { get; set; }
}

class ChartData
{
    String SeriesName { get; set; }
    DateTime SampleTime { get; set; }
    int SampleReading { get; set; }
}
```

For doing this you should merge AllChartData with all nested Readings.

Example:

```
AllChartData: [
    {
        SeriesName : "SeriesName1",
        Readings: [
            {
                SampleTime: "2016.10.1.10:00",
                SampleReading : 3
            },
            {
                SampleTime: "2018.10.1.10:00",
                SampleReading : 67
            },
            {
                SampleTime: "2011.10.1.10:00",
                SampleReading : 36
            },
        ]
    },
    {
        SeriesName : "SeriesName2",
        Readings: [
            {
                SampleTime: "2010.10.1.10:00",
                SampleReading : 76
            },
            {
                SampleTime: "2019.10.1.10:00",
                SampleReading : 89
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        SeriesName : "SeriesName3",
        Readings: [
            {
                SampleTime: "2004.10.1.10:00",
                SampleReading : 7
            },
            {
                SampleTime: "2010.10.1.10:00",
                SampleReading : 8
            }
        ]
    },
]
```

Should be converted to:

```
AllChartData: [
        {
            SeriesName : "SeriesName1",
            SampleTime: "2016.10.1.10:00",
            SampleReading : 3
        },
        {
            SeriesName : "SeriesName1",
            SampleTime: "2018.10.1.10:00",
            SampleReading : 67
        },
        {
            SeriesName : "SeriesName1",
            SampleTime: "2011.10.1.10:00",
            SampleReading : 36
        },      
        {
            SeriesName : "SeriesName2",
            SampleTime: "2010.10.1.10:00",
            SampleReading : 76
        },
        {
            SeriesName : "SeriesName2",
            SampleTime: "2019.10.1.10:00",
            SampleReading : 89
        },
        {
            SeriesName : "SeriesName3",
            SampleTime: "2004.10.1.10:00",
            SampleReading : 7
        },
        {
            SeriesName : "SeriesName3",
            SampleTime: "2010.10.1.10:00",
            SampleReading : 8
        }
]
```

So the SeriesName property will be copied to every nested ChartReading entity.

Comment: Maybe add some explanation?

Comment: After 5 years I have added an explanation... I hope it still is useful for somebody.